# Error adding CocoaPods dependency in Kotlin Multiplatform

Tags: ios, cocoapods, couchbase-lite, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm trying to setup a KMM module with Couchbase Lite as a platform dependency for both Android and iOS. I'm running into errors getting this to work with CocoaPods for iOS:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: /var/folders/pv/3_5xn0dd0v5bf6sxbfcsq_wr0000gn/T/7009311365357251921.m:1:22: error: expected ';' after module name
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.interop.indexer.UtilsKt.ensureNoCompileErrors(Utils.kt:152)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.interop.indexer.ModuleSupportKt.getModulesASTFiles(ModuleSupport.kt:68)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.interop.indexer.ModuleSupportKt.getModulesInfo(ModuleSupport.kt:14)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.interop.gen.jvm.MainKt.buildNativeLibrary(main.kt:507)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.interop.gen.jvm.MainKt.processCLib(main.kt:265)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.interop.gen.jvm.MainKt.interop(main.kt:73)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.utilities.InteropCompilerKt.invokeInterop(InteropCompiler.kt:45)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.utilities.MainKt.mainImpl(main.kt:19)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.utilities.MainKt.main(main.kt:41)
```

The generated `7009311365357251921.m` file is not present at that path afterwards, which makes this difficult to debug.

build.gradle.kts:

```kotlin
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform") version "1.4.21"
    kotlin("native.cocoapods") version "1.4.21"
    id("com.android.library")
}
...
kotlin {
    android()
    ios()
    cocoapods {
        summary = "TBD"
        homepage = "TBD"
        ios.deploymentTarget = "9.0"
        pod("CouchbaseLite-Enterprise") {
            version = "~> 2.8.1"
        }
    }
    ...
}
...
```

I get a different error if I use the non-enterprise release. Same build.gradle.kts except with `pod("CouchbaseLite")`. I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'CBLQueryMeta' is going to be declared twice
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.interop.gen.KotlinFile.<init>(KotlinCodeModel.kt:257)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.interop.gen.StubIrBridgeBuilder$kotlinFile$1.<init>(StubIrBridgeBuilder.kt:44)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.interop.gen.StubIrBridgeBuilder.<init>(StubIrBridgeBuilder.kt:46)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.interop.gen.StubIrDriver.run(StubIrDriver.kt:122)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.interop.gen.jvm.MainKt.processCLib(main.kt:315)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.interop.gen.jvm.MainKt.interop(main.kt:73)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.utilities.InteropCompilerKt.invokeInterop(InteropCompiler.kt:45)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.utilities.MainKt.mainImpl(main.kt:19)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.utilities.MainKt.main(main.kt:41)
```

Both these pod specs compile without problem in an Xcode project. But Kotlin native seems to run into issues with them.

**Update:**

The `pod("CouchbaseLite")` error seems to be caused by having both a `CBLQueryMeta` and `CBLQuery` interface defined. There's a [YouTrack issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-41709) for this. This error will likely still be a problem with `CouchbaseLite-Enterprise`, if the original error could be resolved.

**Update 2:**

If I remove the `{ version = "~> 2.8.1" }` or put it in the function call directly `pod("CouchbaseLite-Enterprise", "~> 2.8.1")` I get a different error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: /var/folders/pv/3_5xn0dd0v5bf6sxbfcsq_wr0000gn/T/6649487835163649080.m:1:9: fatal error: module 'CouchbaseLite_Enterprise' not found
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.interop.indexer.UtilsKt.ensureNoCompileErrors(Utils.kt:152)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.interop.indexer.ModuleSupportKt.getModulesASTFiles(ModuleSupport.kt:68)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.interop.indexer.ModuleSupportKt.getModulesInfo(ModuleSupport.kt:14)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.interop.gen.jvm.MainKt.buildNativeLibrary(main.kt:507)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.interop.gen.jvm.MainKt.processCLib(main.kt:265)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.interop.gen.jvm.MainKt.interop(main.kt:73)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.utilities.InteropCompilerKt.invokeInterop(InteropCompiler.kt:45)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.utilities.MainKt.mainImpl(main.kt:19)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.utilities.MainKt.main(main.kt:41)
```

**Update 3:**

I filed a [YouTrack issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-44235) for this. It seems this might have something to do with the dash - in the CocoaPod library name. There was [an issue](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/issues/2884) that's been closed that had [a fix](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/commit/85908713b14a79c2bf63a269355bf033131b24ba) for this by changing the module name to replace the dash - with an underscore _, but the fix doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which version of the toolchain you're using, seems as if you're using the wrong syntax to specify the version. Try `pod("CouchbaseLite-Enterprise", "~> 2.8.1")` instead.

Comment: I did try this and received a different error. I'll update the question.

Comment: It's not clear why there would be a difference between the two, as the API allows for the version to be specified both ways. The [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/native/cocoapods.html) describe the first way I had it though.